# Can't assign iterator with no viable overloaded '=' error

Tags: c++, stl, unique-ptr

I have a field defined as

```
const vector<record>* data;
```

where record is defined as

```
const unique_ptr<vector<float>> features;
const float label;
```

In my main code, I use

```
vector<record>::iterator iter = data->begin()
```

The compiler isn't happy with my code with the no viable overloaded '=' error at that iterator assignment line. It also produces this warning:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1097:7: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from '__wrap_iter<const_pointer>' to 'const __wrap_iter<class MLx::Example *>' for 1st argument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `vector<record>::const_iterator` work instead? (or `auto` if you have c++11)

Comment: First question: why are you defining `data` as a pointer to a vector? This is *usually* a poor idea in itself. Explicitly typing out the type of an iterator usually signals a problem as well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I'm implementing a wrapping iterator, which derives an abstract iterator. This wrapper has a pointer to the data itself. It's not supposed to manage data.

Is it still a bad idea? What's your suggestion for a better design?

Comment: Another thing is that I tried to simply my code in the question. In my code, *iter* is a field, not a local variable. That's why I needed to explicitly declare its type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"an iterator should be lightweight and should now own the data, i.e. there should be no attempt to copy or even touch record when I make the assignment."*

It has nothing to do with the iterator would *own* the data stored in data `data`, but the `const unique_ptr<>`, restricts accessing the template argument types only as `const` instances.
This means in turn, you need to use

```
vector<record>::const_iterator iter = data->begin();
             // ^^^^^^
```

in your main code.

It's much like writing

```
const vector<record>* data;
```

---

As [@Jonathan Potter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506413/jonathan-potter) mentioned in his comment

```
auto iter = data->begin();
```

should work as well.

Comment: Is it `data` that's const, though?

Comment: Yes, I defined data as const. That's probably why.